# Manjaro / Arch Linux slow GUI after unplugging the HDMI

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, manjaro

I bought a mini-pc to use it as a server, but I need to have the GUI enabled so I can use some software on an external screen. The problem comes when I unplug the HDMI from the PC / I turn on the PC with the HDMI unplugged. The GUI is so slow that it is unusable (I'm connecting through VNC). The problem becomes solved when I plug the HDMI cable at any time. If I unplug it again, the lag comes back.

I'm using Manjaro Xfce, and the VNC Server / Viewer is working correctly. I'm using an 8th gen i5 processor with an integrated graphic card.

Comment: Please include some essential information about the operating system, display manager, what VNC server and client you use, etcetera. There are plenty of things that could affect what you are experiencing. Please note, the main focus is now on your problem but will remain here indefinitely for future readers. Please make some more effort to help yourself and others as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Desktop background on the remote machine to white (or perhaps another solid color) may help.

See [TIP: Greatly increase remote vncserver performance](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=5363)  in the Xfce Forums, and [Tips & Tricks - Performance Tips - Background Color](https://wiki.xfce.org/tips#background_color) on the Xfce Wiki.

My thinking is that:

1. since the remote machine is responsive to the presence or absence of the HDMI cable, then
2. the response to the HDMI cable is likely affecting the graphic processing on the remote machine, which is perhaps in turn
3. affecting the speed of processing of the graphic information for transmission via the VNC connection.

So any adjustment to reduce graphic processing, such as use of a white background rather than some image as suggested by the sites above, might help.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak The essential part is to change the background.

Comment: Of course I did. I've added my reasoning to my answer for readers' edification.

Comment: I believe we don't have enough information from the OP (yet),... which is a shame, it is a rather good question indeed missing a lot of information. Anyhow, thank you for your time and effort!